# Fourier Transform Units

Tags: fourier-transform

It is documented that 'one' of the units of the Fourier Transform [of $x(t)$ volt] is volt per Hz. That is $X(\omega)$ components will have units of volt per Hz, where $\omega$ is the angular frequency (along the $x$-axis).

For example, the Fourier Transform of $\cos(\omega_0 t)$ volt has two components - one at $\omega = \omega_0$ and one at $\omega = -\omega_0$, each assigned a 'value' of $\pi$. So it is assumed that the values are '$\pi$ volt per Hz'.

Now, when the plot is adjusted to become a function of cyclic frequency $f$ (in Hz), which means plotting $X(f)$ versus $f$, then the Fourier Transform components of $\cos( 2\pi f_0 t)$ become '1/2 or 0.5' instead of '$\pi$'.

My question is --- why isn't the '$\pi$ volt per Hz' preserved when translating between $X(\omega)$ and $X(f)$?

According to tables showing Fourier Transform pairs, the Fourier Transform of  $\cos( 2\pi f_0 t)$ volt has two components -- each with a value of '1/2 or 0.5'. For these values, does anyone know what their units are? I had assumed that the values for each component would have been 'preserved' (to be $\pi$ volt per Hz), regardless of whether we do the plot as a function of '$\omega_0$' rad/s or a function of '$f_0$' Hz.

Comment: remember, both **radian** and **cycle** (or "**turn**") are dimensionless.  and remember that the $\mathrm{d}t$ has dimension of time and $\mathrm{d}f$ or $\mathrm{d}\omega$ have dimension of frequency (or 1/time).

Answer (score 1):

For a given signal $g(t)$ with Fourier transform $G(\omega)$:

$$g(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} G(\omega)e^{i\omega t}\textrm{d}\omega$$

If you change variables such that $\omega=2\pi f$

$$g(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} G(2\pi f)e^{i2\pi ft}\textrm{d}(2\pi f)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} G(2\pi f)e^{i2\pi ft}\textrm{d}f$$

So if you present your Fourier transform as a function of $f$ instead of $\omega$, your Fourier pair of $g(t)$ will now be $\hat{G}(f)=\frac{G(2\pi f)}{2\pi}$ and:

$$g(t) =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{G}(f)e^{i2\pi ft}\textrm{d}f$$

Note that with this definition, there is a scaling of $2\pi$ in comparison with the first equation I wrote. So now, for example, the Fourier transform of a cosine will consist of two deltas not with amplitude $\pi$, but with amplitude $\frac{\pi}{2\pi}=\frac12$, as correctly stated in your question.

Comment: you have too many "$f$'s" appearing in your integrals (except the top one).  there is a reason why electrical engineering textbooks stay away from labeling functions "$f(\cdot)$".

Comment: Thanks very much Tendero and robert! Tendero ---- some sources use the units of volt per hz (for the Fourier Transform X(w) if the time function x(t) has units of volts. But if we plot X(f), then what units would that become in relation to the X(w) units? Also, Tendero.... for your second equation, if you have the 1/(2.pi) out the front of the integral, then doesn't this mean that f(t) transforms to 2.pi.F(2.pi.f)? This also means f(t) transforms to 2.pi.F(w), right? I can see that you wrote f(t) transforms to F(2.pi.f)/(2.pi), but don't quite understand how that link was made. Thanks again!

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson  You are right, I've changed the names. Thanks!

Comment: @Kenny The units of $X(f)$ and $X(\omega)$ stay the same. It's just the magnitude that changes. Regarding the second question, note the following: $$g(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{G(\omega)}{2\pi}e^{i\omega t}\textrm{d}\omega = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{G}(f)e^{i2\pi ft}\textrm{d}f$$

Comment: @Kenny Glad to help. If the answer solved your question, please accept it by clicking on the check mark next to it, so it can help future readers as well.

Comment: Tendero..... thanks for helping me out with that. According to this equation, does it mean that g(t) transforms to G(w)/(2.pi), rather than g(t) transforming to G(w)? Also..... G_hat(f) is the same as G(2.pi.f), which is the same as G(w), right? So the equation you wrote appears to be saying that G(w)/(2.pi) = G_hat(f) = G(w)? So G(w)/(2.pi) is G(w)? My assumption is that G(2.pi.f) is a function of 'w' since 2.pi.f is 'w', and it is also a function of 'f'.

Comment: @Kenny No, $G(\omega)$ is what it is. Nowhere it is stated that $G(\omega) = G(\omega)/(2\pi)$, that would be non-sense for any $G(\omega)\neq 0$. $g(t)$ transforms to $G(\omega)$, the dividing $2\pi$ comes from the definition of the inverse Fourier transform. I put it inside the integral for you to see where the equality $\hat{G}(f)=\frac{G(2\pi f)}{2\pi}$ came from.

Comment: Ok! Thanks very much for explaining that Tendero. My main issue was that one expression is integration with 'w', while the other is integrating with 'f', so that G(w)/(2pi) could only be compared properly with G_hat(f) if both expressions are integrated with the same variable (ie. w), right?

Comment: @Kenny Yes, the variable should be the same. That's why if you evaluate the first integral at $\omega = 2\pi f$ you get the second one, and thus the scalating factor.

Comment: Thansk Tendero. One quick question... According to your definition of G_hat(f), your third equation from your original post should be : $$g(t) =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 2\pi\hat{G}(f)e^{i2\pi ft}\textrm{d}f$$ right? That's based on the middle expression of your second equation.

Comment: And the other equation you wrote is probably meant to be: $$g(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{G(2\pi f)}{2\pi}e^{i2\pi ft}\textrm{d}(2\pi f)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}2\pi \hat{G}(f)e^{i2\pi ft}\textrm{d}f$$ right? Thanks Tendero.

Comment: If we cancel the $2\pi$ terms in the middle expression above, then the result appears to be saying that $G(2\pi f)=2\pi\hat{G}(2\pi f)$, which implies $G(2\pi f) = G(2\pi f)$ ?

Comment: Hi Tendero! While I'm sure that the 'pi' value in G($\omega$) versus $\omega$ and the '1/2' value in the G(f) versus f plot allows the integrated results (within each variable) to come out to the correct values ..... to arrive at g(t)...... I still don't know the 'units' associated with G(f). When plotted with $\omega$, a spike might have a value of pi volt per Hz. When it is plotted with 'f', the spike has a value of 1/2 ....... but I have no idea what its units are.

Comment: @Kenny The units are the same, just that in one case the horizontal axis is in Hz and in the other one, in rad/s. So the amplitude should correspond to that unit for the plot to make sense. Remember that $$\mathrm{Hz} = 2\pi \mathrm{\frac{rad}{s}}$$

Comment: Thanks Tendero! Could you please check to see whether your original equation had a mistake in it? The initial post has a G_hat(f) definition. Your second equation from the original post has a 1/(2pi) out the front, which is then brought inside the integral, which then forms the G_hat(f) expression, ie. G(2.pi.f)/(2pi). However, the middle expression also contains a 2pi term in the tail-end of it. So the middle equation will end up having a 2.pi.G_hat_(f) term within the integral, with 'f' being the variable of integration. So the third equation should have 2pi.G_hat(f), not G_hat(f).

Comment: Also, the units of volt per Hz corresponds to plots associated with angular frequency (rad/s). So that alone is quite an interesting thing in itself. So that's why I'm trying to understand what's going on here. Normally, when we plot Y-axis values, against something else, the values and units of the Y-axis remain the same - regardless of whether the Y-value is a density value or not. But, it appears that - for the case of Fourier Transform plots, the Y-axis value is changed or scaled - depending on a 'w' plot or 'f' plot. I assumed Y-axis values should stay the same.

Comment: So....what I'm trying to say is.... if for a particular value of 'w', the units of the Y-value is "pi" volt per Hz (under the assumption of g(t) is volt and time is seconds), then at the equivalent (same) frequency in 'f' Hz, the value should also be "pi" volt per Hz....from the point of view of an observer. But clearly, the Fourier Transform tables indicate a value of '1/2' (for 'f' plots). I have no problem with this. I'm just interested in finding out what the units are for the '1/2'. So is it pi volt per Hz, or 1/2 volt per Hz? Thanks again Tendero!

Comment: Hi all! This question doesn't appear to be answered yet (even though attempts at answers have been posted). Feel free to add comments to answer the question. Main question is --- if pi volt per Hz when plotted with angular frequency 'w', then what are the units for the 0.5 (ie. 1/2) when plotted against cyclic frequency frequency 'f'? The units are expected to be different. If not, then an explanation and demonstration would be handy.Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Hz is in units of cycles per second.

ω is in units of radians per second.

And there are 2 π radians per cycle.

Comment: remember, both **radian** and **cycle** (or "**turn**") are dimensionless.

Comment: They might be "dimensionless", but they have a ratio between them.

Comment: yup, just like the length of radii of a circle has with the length of the circumference.